# TMUX - setting up vi mode

Tags: tmux

I heard much good about TMUX but so far I am just failing with the setup.
I would like to use the vi mode that allows you to copy with "SPACE" an "ENTER".
Currently I must use CTRL+SPACE and ALT+W.

I am running KALI 5.9.0 and TMUX 3.1c
When I run TMUX and check the setting it shows me the following:

```
$ tmux show -g status-keys
status-keys emacs
$ tmux show -g mode-keys  
mode-keys emacs
```

My ~/.tmux.conf files looks like this:

```
set-window-option -g status-keys vi
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

I also tried the following two:

```
setw -g status-keys vi
setw -g mode-keys vi
```

```
set -g status-keys vi
set -g mode-keys vi
```

I killed all tmux session and checked again but it seems as something is permanently overwriting my vi mode.
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried reloading your config file? `<prefix>:source-file ~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: It helped! By doing so I saw that it was complaining about my input lines. Didn't really see a mistake and just deleted everything and typed it in new. Maybe some copy paste issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my .bashrc, and when I run tmux everything's still in vi mode:

```
# use vi shortcuts in terminal
set -o vi
```